# Узнать id выбранного элемента $('input:file')

Tags: javascript, ajax, fileupload

Есть три формы для выбора файлов, планируется загрузка на сервак ajaxом, mysqli insert_id (внесение информации о пользователе директории и новом имени файла в скуль), и подставление полученного insert_id в значение скрытого поля, для отправки на сервер целиком формы, но уже без обработки файлов.

```
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Добавьте фото ТМЦ</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="wt_no_photo_add_file" id="wt_no_photo_add_file">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="wt_no_photo_add" id="wt_no_photo_add" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Добавьте скан гарантийного талона</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="wt_no_scangarant_add_file" id="wt_no_scangarant_add_file" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="wt_no_scangarant_add" id="wt_no_scangarant_add" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Добавьте скан сертификата</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="wt_no_certificate_add_file" id="wt_no_certificate_add_file">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="wt_no_certificate_add" id="wt_no_certificate_add" value="">
                                        </div>
```

Собственно вопрос, как мне узнать id или имя выбранной формы загрузки файла для внесения изменений согласно js коду ниже

```
 <script>
                                        $('input:file').on('change', function () {
                                            var data = new FormData();
                                            //Append files infos
                                            alert(this.name);
                                            jQuery.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file) {
                                                data.append('file-'+i, file);
                                            });
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: "ajaxupload.php",
                                                type: "POST",
                                                data: data,
                                                cache: false,
                                                processData: false,
                                                contentType: false,
                                                context: this,
                                                success: function (msg) {
                                                    if(msg)
                                                    {
                                                        tmp = msg.split('~');
                                                        if(tmp[0]==='success') {
                                                            document.getElementById(tmp[2]).value = tmp[1];
                                                        }
                                                        else if(tmp[0]==='danger') alert(tmp[1]);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
```

P.S. Извиняюсь за гигантские отступы

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, оказалось простым

```
this.name
```